# Issue with the CSS flexbox to set the items in columns

Tags: html, css

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnaHO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqOb.png)

I'm having some issues with the cozy tea proyect I need it like that and I can move from here, what I have for that it is:

I have this so far for that

```css
.Locations {
  background-image: url("img-locations-background.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 300px;
  font-size: 22px;
  align-items: center;
}

.Locations h2 {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="Locations">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>downtown</h3>
    <p>384 west 4th St<br> suite 108<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>East bayside</h3>
    <p>3433 phisherman's avenue<br> (northwest corner)<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>Oakdale</h3>
    <p>515 Crescent avenue<br> second floor<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the flexbox wrap to next row and wrap all the elements after `h2` to the following row.

```css
.Locations {
  background-image: url("img-locations-background.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* making the flexbox wrap to next row */
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 300px;
  font-size: 22px;
  align-items: center;
}

.Locations h2 {
  flex: 1 1 100%; /* making flex item to span 100% */
}
```

```html
<div class="Locations">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>downtown</h3>
    <p>384 west 4th St<br> suite 108<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>East bayside</h3>
    <p>3433 phisherman's avenue<br> (northwest corner)<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
  <div class="locations-box">
    <h3>Oakdale</h3>
    <p>515 Crescent avenue<br> second floor<br> Portland, Maine</p>
  </div>
</div>
```